# Pressing back button throws huge exception

Tags: exception, flutter

Everytime I try to press my phone's back button flutter consoles throws this exception. If I just try to POP from a built-in button this doesn't happend. What might be caused by? I don't really understand.

The exception goes on till n° 400 and than stoppes and eventually goes back to the previous screen

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown while dispatching notifications for FocusManager:
Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe.

At this point the state of the widget's element tree is no longer stable.

To safely refer to a widget's ancestor in its dispose() method, save a reference to the ancestor by calling inheritFromWidgetOfExactType() in the widget's didChangeDependencies() method.

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      Element._debugCheckStateIsActiveForAncestorLookup.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3406:9)
#1      Element._debugCheckStateIsActiveForAncestorLookup (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3420:6)
#2      Element.inheritFromWidgetOfExactType (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3435:12)
#3      Focus.of (package:flutter/src/widgets/focus_scope.dart:266:41)
#4      _InkResponseState._handleFocusUpdate (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:629:39)
...
The FocusManager sending notification was: FocusManager#2a4e1
  primaryFocus: FocusScopeNode#e5462
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ (2) Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════
Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe.
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ (3) Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════
Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe.
═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

Comment: You should provide the code that is causing the issue. So that people can help you. Please provide the code.

Comment: I don't really know what code to provide, this happens everywhere in my app and I can't provide you the entire project

Comment: Are you overriding the dispose of the widget where you are pressing the back button? if yes can you provide that code?